# How to determine if the json result has an array object named data and get all of its parent object names

Tags: c#, json

I have Web API dynamic returns as follow:

```
{
    "result": true,
    "payload": {
        "data": [
            {
                "class": "Platinum",
                "name": "William",
                "title": "Mr."
            },
            {
                "class": "Silver",
                "name": "Susan",
                "title": "Ms."
            },
            {
                "class": "Platinum",
                "name": "Jack",
                "title": "Mr."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to determine if that json returning has an array object named "data" and the get it's parent object (in the above case the parent object is "payload" so I would able to retrieve the array value by using eg.

```
 (JArray)jo[payload][data]
```

I need advice, thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use somethin like this

```
     var dataArr = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("payload.data");

    if (dataArr != null && dataArr.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        foreach (var item in dataArr) {}
        //or
        var data = dataArr.Select(o => new  { Class=o["class"], ...});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries like `Newtonsoft.Json` to parse and check.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(yourJsonDate);
if (jObject["payload"] is JObject payload && payload["data"] is JArray data)
{
    // Access the array values under "data"
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("JSON structure doesn't contain expected elements.");
}
```

Comment: Hi you almost there!, but how about if use variable for the "payload" and "data" ?
eg. 
string x1 = "payload";
string x2 = "data";

I was thinking about like if (jObject[x1] is JObject x1 && x1[x2] is JArray x2)
{

Comment: Absolutely! You can use variables to access the JSON properties dynamically.